# Linux: ошибка обновления

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update

Поставил обновление+по неопытности удалил python3.5 в директории  /usr/bin. Сейчас выдаёт ошибку: problem occurred when checking for updates.

Comment: Не ясно что за инструмент используется для обновления. Вы можете выполнить `sudo apt-get update` в терминале и показать выхлоп. Если `apt-get` работает без ошибок, то попробуйте установить python с её помощью.

Comment: пробуйте инструкции по этой [ ссылке | http://compizomania.blogspot.com/2013/05/ubuntu-13041210.html ]

Comment: Комбинации из комманд `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo aptitude reinstall python3.5` и `dpkg --configure -a` должны помочь.